# Joint distribution of hitting times for brownian motion with drift

Tags: brownian-motion, supremum-and-infimum, density-function

I'm stuck with the following question: Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Brownian Motion (BM) with drift $\mu > 0$ on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}, \mathbb{P})$. That is, $B_t := \hat{B}_t + \mu t$, where $\hat{B}_t$ is a standard BM. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\tau_x := \inf \{ t \geq 0: B_t = x \}$ be the hitting time of the level $x$. 
I'm interested in calculating the probability that the BM with drift reaches some level $a$ before reaching the level $-b$, that is:
$$\mathbb{P}[\tau_a < \tau_{-b}] \ \  \text{for}  \ \ a, b > 0$$
I am aware how to do this in the driftless case via the reflection principle. Here is my take on the case with drift using Girsanovs theorem:

For $\mu > 0$, consider $\hat{B}_t := B_t - \mu t$. By defining the process $Z_T = \exp \{ \mu W_T - \frac{\mu^2}{2} T \}$ for some fixed $T > 0$ we can use Girsanovs theorem to construct a measure $\mathbb{Q}_T$ via $\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}_T = Z_T\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}_T$, such that w.r.t $\mathbb{Q}_T$ $\hat{B}_t$ is a Brownian motion on $[0,T]$. $(\mathbb{P}_T := \mathbb{P}|_{\mathcal{F}_T}$ is the restriction of $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathcal{F}_T$.)
Consequently, and more importantly, $B_t = \hat{B}_t + \mu t$ is a Brownian motion with drift under $\mathbb{Q}_T$. So:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{Q}_T[\tau_a < \tau_{-b}] &= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}_{T}} [1_{ \{ \tau_a < \tau_{-b}\} }] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}_{T}} [1_{ \{ \tau_a < \tau_{-b}\} } Z_T] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}_{T}} [1_{ \{ \tau_a < \tau_{-b}\} }\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}_{T}}[Z_T | \mathcal{F}_{\tau_a}]] \\ 
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}_{T}} [1_{ \{ \tau_a < \tau_{-b}\} } Z_{\tau_a}]  \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}_{T}} [1_{ \{ \tau_a < \tau_{-b}\} } \exp \{ \mu a - \frac{\mu^2}{2} \tau_a \}]
\end{align}
There are 2 things that confuse me about this:

(1) I'm not sure how to deal about the fact that Girsanovs theorem only allows to construct a measure on a finite time horizon. The event $\{ \tau_a < \tau_{-b} \} $ is not even measurable w.r.t $\mathcal{F}_T$. Can I overcome this by simply considering $\hat{\tau}_a := \tau_a \wedge T$ and $\hat{\tau}_{-b} := \tau_{-b} \wedge T$ and then in the end take the limit $T \rightarrow \infty$?

(2) I don't know how to evaluate the last expression. If I knew the **joint** density of $\tau_a$ and $\tau_{-b}$ I could calculate it as:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^t \exp \{ \mu a - \frac{\mu^2}{2} s \} f_{\tau_a, \tau_{-b}}(s,t) \ \mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t$$
Finding this density is equivalent to finding the joint distribution of the infimum and the supremum of Brownian Motion. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tricky answer.

Lets find a function $v(t)$ such that $U_t = v(B_t)$ is a martingale. By Ito's formula we have, in the integral form,
$$ U_T - U_0 = \int_0^T \mu v'(B_t) dt + \int_0^T \sigma v'(B_t) d\hat B_t + \frac{\sigma^2}2\int_0^T v''(B_t) dt, $$
that we got using Ito's formula on $v(B_t) = v(f(\hat B_t, t))$ where $f(x,t) = \sigma x + \mu t$ and $\hat{B}_t$ is the underlying Brownian motion.

Then:
$$
\begin{align}
\Bbb E(U_{T+h}- U_T\mid\mathcal F_T)& =\Bbb E\left(\left.\int_T^{T+h}\mu v'(B_t)dt+\int_T^{T+h}\sigma v'(B_t) d\hat B_t+\frac{\sigma^2}2\int_T^{T+h} v''(B_t) dt\right|~\mathcal F_T \right)\\& = \Bbb E\left( \left.
\int_T^{T+h}\mu v'(B_t)+ \frac{\sigma^2}2 v''(B_t)dt \right|~\mathcal F_T\right)+\Bbb E\left(\left.
\int_T^{T+h} \sigma v'(B_t) d\hat B_t \right|~\mathcal F_T \right)
\end{align}$$
Now we use the fact that if $X_s$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_s$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_s^2) < \infty$ for all $s\geq 0$, then $Y_t = \int_0^t X_s d\hat{B}_s$ is a martingale. In that case, as we'll see, $X_s = v'(B_s) = e^{-\lambda (\sigma \hat{B}_s + \mu s)}$ is a lognormal r.v. and therefore, is square integrable. Note that we have to justify this step after finding the formula for $v$. Besides that, since $\hat B_s$ is $\mathcal F_s$-measurable, $X_s$ is adapted to $\mathcal F_s$. So:
$$\Bbb E\left( \left.
\int_T^{T+h}\sigma v'(B_t)d\hat B_t \right|~\mathcal F_T\right)=0 $$

A martingale satisfies $\Bbb E( U_{T+h}- U_T\mid\mathcal F_T ) = 0$, then
$$\mu v'(x)+\frac{\sigma^2}2v''(x)=0\implies v''(x)=-\lambda v'(x) $$
where $\lambda = \frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}$.

Choosing (because we can) $v'(0)=1$ and $v(0)=0$ we have
$$v'(x) = e^{-\lambda x} \implies v(x) = \int_0^x e^{-\lambda t} dt = \frac{1 - e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda}.$$

And so $U_t= v(B_t)$ is a martingale. The renormalization $v(x)$ is a continuous monotone increasing function, then
$$ \Bbb P( \tau_a < \tau_{-b} ) = \Bbb P\left( \tau'_{v(a)} < \tau'_{v(-b)}\right) $$
where $\tau'_x = \inf\{ t\geq 0 : U_t = x \}$.

Now let $v>w$, since $U_t$ is a martingale (see [this text](http://www.eco.uc3m.es/%7Emkredler/ContTime/5ExitTimes.pdf)),
$$ \Bbb P( \tau'_v < \tau'_w ) = \frac{U_0-w}{v-w}, $$
and so
$$\Bbb P( \tau_a < \tau_{-b} ) = \frac{v(B_0)-v(-b)}{v(a)-v(-b)}. $$

Since $B_0 = 0$ with probability one:
$$\Bbb P( \tau_a < \tau_{-b} ) = \frac{v(0)-v(-b)}{v(a)-v(-b)} = \frac{e^{\lambda b}-1}{e^{\lambda b}-e^{-\lambda a}} .$$

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this insightful answer! While (I think that) I understand the general idea, I'm struggling with the rigorous formulation of some of the steps.

Do you mean by $\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{d}U_t \vert \mathcal{F}_t] = v'(B_t) \mu \mathrm{d}t + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} v''(B_t) \mathrm{d}t$ that $\mathbb{E}[U_t  \vert \mathcal{F}_t] = \mathbb{E}[U_0] + \int_0^t v'(B_s) \mu \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t  \frac{\sigma^2}{2} v''(B_s) \mathrm{d}s$? (forgive me if this question is stupid, I know that the notation you used is standard in stochastic calculus but I'm still struggling with it.)

Comment: If so, how do you reason a priori that $\mathbb{E}[v'(B_s) \mathrm{d} W_s] = 0$, and with a priori I mean before specifying a function $v$. It is not clear to me why this should hold since in general the Itô Integral is only a local martingale.
Even with the explicit choice $v(x) = \frac{1 - e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda}$ I'm not sure how to show that the process $Y_t := \int_0^t e^{-\lambda (W_s + \mu s )}\mathrm{d} W_s$ has zero expectation.

Comment: Then I think that you mean  that the boundary condition should be $v(0) = 0$ and $v(x) = \int_0^x e^{-\lambda y} \mathrm{d}y$ (without the $1$ in front of the integral)

Comment: And finally, i don't understand why you need the SDE for Ut. Since v is bijective and monote (as you wrote), we clearly have $\mathbb{P}[\tau_a < \tau_b] = \mathbb{P}[\tau'_{v(a)} < \tau'_{v(b)}]$. (with your notation.) If it was clear that $U$ is a martingale, we could consider the stopping time $\tau := \tau'_{v(a)} \wedge \tau'_{v(b)}$. I'm pretty sure that it can be shown via a Borel Cantelli argument that $\tau \in L^1$.

Comment: Hence by optional sampling we have (since $U_0=0$ a.s. by construction) $0 = \mathbb{E}[U_\tau] = U_{\tau'_{v(a)}} \mathbb{P}[\tau'_{v(a)} < \tau'_{v(b)}] + U_{\tau'_{v(b)}} \mathbb{P}[\tau'_{v(a)} > \tau'_{v(b)}] = v(a) \mathbb{P}[\tau'_{v(a)} < \tau'_{v(b)}] + v(b) (1 - \mathbb{P}[\tau'_{v(a)} < \tau'_{v(b)}])$. This implies $\mathbb{P}[\tau'_{v(a)} < \tau'_{v(b)}]=\frac{v(b)}{v(b)−v(a)}$.

Comment: I try to make it more rigirous and to use the integral form, I hope you enjoy it. And about your final argument, it seems to work and is more elegant.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to give and edit the answer. I have accepted it for now since it clearly presented a technique how to solve this problem. However I still don't see why you can pull out some things of the integral and of the expectation. Why should for example $\mathbb{E}[\int_T^{T+h} \mu v'(B_t) dt \vert \mathcal{F}_T ] = \mu v'(B_T)  \mathbb{E}[\int_T^{T+h}  dt \vert \mathcal{F}_T ] $? Also I don't understand what you mean by $v'(B_t) = f(\hat{B}_t , t) = \sigma x + \mu t$. Isn't $v'$ a general function we know nothing about a priori?

Comment: I'm sorry for this confusion. My argument was simply wrong, I've commuted operations that can't be commuted. Now it is fixed. And about $v'$ it was a typo, I also fixed it, I just wanted to clarify that $v(B_t)$, in fact, has two variables, the values of $\hat{B}_t$ and $t$. That way it is clear how to fit $v$ in Ito's formula.

Comment: Now it is clear, thank you very much for all your effort and also the reference you posted! I searched a lot for results like this but could not find it anywhere :)